# How do I make this contact form function in the correct way with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I've created and styled a simple contact form on my website, but the form isn't actually bringing through the information from the input fields. Even when I fill the form out, I simply get this:
[image]

How do I fix this? And also, how would I go about ensuring the submit only fires when the fields are correctly filled out? Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="form-container">
            
        <section class="contact-wrap">
<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="mail.php">
    
    <div class="col1">
<p><label>Name</label><br />
    <input type="text" value-size="40" placeholder="name"></p>
        </div>
    
    <div class="col1">
 <p><label>Email</label><br />
     <input type="text" value-size="40" placeholder="email"></p>  
    </div>
    
    <div class="col1">
 <p><label>Business Name</label><br />
     <input type="text" value-size="40" placeholder="business"></p> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="col1">
    <p><label>Website</label><br />
        <input type="text" value-size="40" placeholder="website"></p> 
    </div>
    
    
 <p><label>How can I help you?</label><br />
     <textarea  placeholder="message"></textarea></p> 
<p><input type="submit" value="Send"></p>         
</form>
</section>
            
                </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Business Name: $business \n Website: $website \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "hi@helloarchie.co";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header( 'Location: thankyou.php' );
?>
```

Comment: Your input elements **must** have names so that they appear in the POST array when the form is submitted

Comment: Your HTML is also invalid - a `label` element is intended to be associated with an input element rather than to hold arbitrary HTML content. That association is done either using `for=ID of input` type syntax or by completely wrapping the input element itself within the label. By doing that you can also very easily affect the layout using CSS rather than using `BR` tags and `P` tags to accomplish that

Comment: Thank you! I'll work on changing that.

Comment: I would suggest that you use `isset` (which will accept multiple arguments) to test that **all** required POST fields are actually present before blindly assigning them as variables. The `required` attribute in HTML does not guarantee that these will be in the POST array!

Answer (score 0):

first, you‘re missing the name-tag for the input-fields.

It should fix you’re problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).